# saveAsCassandraTable is not a member of ....dstream.DStream[(String, Int, String)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I am getting the below error when i am trying to load real time tweets to Cassandra using **saveAsCassandraTable**

`value saveAsCassandraTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[(String, Int, String)]`

I am able to successfully export using **saveToCassandra** though. The code so far i could put together is below -

```
val tags = stream.map(_.getText).filter(_.startsWith("@xyz"))     
val Counts  =   tags.map((_, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow((x: Int, y: Int) => x + y, windowLength, slideInterval)    
val CountsAll   =   Counts.map{case (tag,   counter) => (tag,   counter, "Everything")}    
CountsAll.saveAsCassandraTable("demo1", "tags1")
```

My requirement is scala load the tweets to two different tables in Cassandra at the same time.
One is a predefined table in Cassandra and another is to create a table on the fly every time tweets are loaded. The tweets are loaded at 2000 sec interval.

Appreciate any suggestions on how to do a `saveAsCassandraTable`

Answer (score 3):

Like @user6910411 said, your error tells you that you're trying to call `saveAsCassandraTable` on a `DStream`. 
You can only use it on an [RDD[T]](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/72c4bc6703b71854746d35a8f8cc2108f48f6730/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/RDDFunctions.scala#L18), in your case `RDD[(String, Int, String)]`.

You want something like this:

```
CountsAll.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
   rdd.saveAsCassandraTable("demo1", "tags1")
}
```

**UPDATE**

The RDD API doesn't support truncating etc.
You should probably look to manage schema outside of your Spark code path.
However, to directly address what you've asked for:

```
val conn: CassandraConnector = CassandraConnector(sparkConf())
conn.withSessionDo { session =>
      session.execute(s"""CREATE TABLE tags1..."")
      }
    }
```

where `sparkConf()` returns the spark config object with the Cassandra settings.
`.withSessionDo` gives you a `Session` object from the DataStax C* driver so you can do whatever you want with it.
Again, I'd recommend schema management is not done directly on your Spark code path and is managed independently.

Comment: ...thankyou. I tried your above suggestions but it is throwing a Java Exception error : com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AlreadyExistsException: Table demo1.tags1 already exists. In cassandra i am seeing the this error - InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table tags1" My requirement is to truncate or over write the tabel and load every time a new tweet is streamed. I was saveAsCassandraTable would overwrite the existing table.